# VS Code C++ File Not Found - Include Path Errors

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to #include header files from an external library that I cloned from Github, and VS code warns me "cannot open source file '...filename...'".

Info: The external library I am referring to is the [LLVM project](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project), an solid tool for code analysis. Both the programming language which I am writing in, as well as trying to do analysis on is C++.

What I have tried so far is to include the absolute path, take the "ASTMatchers.h" for example, changing from

```
#include "clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h"
```

to

```
#include "llvm-project/clang/include/clang/ASTMatchers/ASTMatchers.h"
```

now the file can be found during the linking phase, but soon as C++ looks into "ASTMatchers.h", it cannot find other header files defined in the ASTMatchers.

Additionally, I have tried to reorganize my files around in the project folder. For instance, placing the main.cpp inside the external lib, or outside of it.

My understanding of this issue is that I should use tools like CMake for this purpose, however it might also be due to my lack of knowledge in how C++ compliation works.

What I have checked: I made sure the file namings are correct, and the g++ complier is installed properly.

Any suggestions or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I preach to not have paths in the `#include`, opting to pass the search directories to the compiler.  This allows my code to move without having to change the files.

Comment: Never move files or edit #include directives to solve this kind of problem, instead tell your compiler where the header files are. With VSCode (in a typical configuration) this would involve editting tasks.json to add the relevant compiler options. LLVM is seriously large and complex library, I wonder how you are going to make good use of it when you don't understand how C++ complilation works.